# SQL query that removes all rows with certain value?

Tags: sql

I am trying to perform a SQL query that removes all the rows where people have less then 10 people or more then 100 people in their network.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 Where inNetwork > 10 AND < 1000,
```

Basically, by this query what I mean is only show people with more then 10 and less then 1000 people in their network but it isn't working but when I try only 1 number e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 Where inNetwork > 10
```

then it works but I want to remove two types of data.

Comment: why give negative vote? did I ask something wrong?

Comment: I didn't down vote, but some sample data sure would help.

Comment: but doesn't the query itself explains what I am after? everything is working in the query except the stuff after AND. I was missing the BETWEEN keyword, which fabio pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `BETWEEN` to achieve this

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE inNetwork BETWEEN 10 AND 1000;
```

Otherwise you will need to express both condition for your column

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE inNetwork > 10 
AND inNetwork < 1000;
```

Comment: can I ask you one more question?

Comment: say for example I have series of names of people and how many times their have sent a message, how would I find out who sent the most message.

Comment: If i understood you correctly you can use max() on the column messages and group by user if you need to find the maximum message any user have sent

Comment: say for example, the row of people name is called name and message sent it called message, would the query be something like SELECT * FROM table1 MAX(name), GROUP BY name, message;

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49307/discussion-between-fabio-and-seeker)

Comment: Between is not what Seeker is looking for, because that *includes* the limit values. Between is equivalent to `inNetwork >= 10 and inNetwork <= 1000`

Comment: @Fabio hi, need your help again :) let me know when your free

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
Where inNetwork > 10 
  AND inNetwork < 1000;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   table1
Where  inNetwork > 10 
AND    inNetwork < 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name BETWEEN value1 AND value2;
```

Comment: Between includes the values specified, so it's equivalent to `col >= 10 and col <= 1000` which is not what the OP wants

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove rows where they have >10 OR <100 then:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 Where inNetwork > 10
OR inNetwork < 100
```

That will select each row that has either of those conditions.  However, I'm not sure this query makes sense.  What if inNetwork is 1500?  Perhaps you meant between 10 and 100?